# Within a transaction check the first update succeeded

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I intend to write a SQL transaction to insert an order if a product has enough inventory (make sure no two customers both success to buy a product with only 1 inventory at the same time), like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE products SET inventory=inventory-1 WHERE product_id=1 AND inventory>=1;
  if (update succeeded) INSERT order ...;
COMMIT;
```

How can I check whether the products' inventory update succeeded. Do I have to use the procedure?

Comment: Why would an `order` have only one `product`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is just an example, at the beginning I am thinking to implement `insert orders` and `insert order_products` within a `TRANSACTION`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an *after-update* trigger  that inserts an order. You can also select the `products.product_id` into a variable and check whether that's greater than 0. Of course, this variable approach only works if there is a single `products` record to be updated. If there are plural such records, then you can use a cursor instead of a variable. I believe that the simplest approach is to implement a trigger, so you will have a single visible operation in the transaction and the insertion would be performed by the trigger under the hood.